# Why does the 'this' in the prototype refer to the global context while the 'this' in the declaration refers to the function?

Tags: javascript, this

Why does the `this` in the prototype refer to the global context while the `this` in the declaration refers to the function? Even when trying to explicitly set the context of `this` it still refers to the global context.

```
var Foo = function (a) {
  console.log(this); // this will refer to global context
  this.bar = () => {
    // this refers to function context
    return a;
  };
};


Foo.prototype = {
  biz: () => {
    return this.bar(); // this this will refer to global context
  },
};

var f = new Foo(7);
f.biz(); // this.bar is not a function
f.biz.call(f); // this.bar is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you declared the `biz` method as an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#arrow_functions_used_as_methods). You should generally not do that because an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#arrow_functions_used_as_methods) retains `this` when it is **declared** (not when it **executes**).

Replace `biz` with a regular function like this:

```js
var Foo = function (a) {
  console.log(this); // this will refer to global context
  this.bar = () => {
    // this refers to function context
    return a;
  };
};


Foo.prototype = {
  biz() {
    return this.bar();
  },
};

var f = new Foo(7);
f.biz(); // Works
f.biz.call(f); // Works even if not needed
```

Comment: If it retains `this` when it's declared, why doesn't the `this` in `this.bar` continue to refer to the global context? Is it not getting it's context from `f` when it's called with `f.bar()`?

Comment: @MatthewMoran because when it's declared, `this` wasn't `window`.

Comment: How is it not the window? The console log above it refers to the global context.

Comment: @MatthewMoran `this.bar` is being declared in the context of the constructor, where `this` is what you expect (the current instance)

Comment: Why is there a different between the `this` in the log above `this.bar` and `this.bar`?

Comment: @MatthewMoran "*The console log above it refers to the global context*" only if you call `Foo` without `new`. You don't do that, so `this` is an instance of `Foo`. https://jsbin.com/zazasus/edit?js,console

Comment: @VLAZ, the log prints out `this` as the global context when using new as well. It prints out when the instance is created.

Comment: @MatthewMoran see the example I posted. It doesn't.

Comment: Ah I see my confusion. Running in Node (not strict mode) it shows `this` in the log to be `{}` which is the same as the global context in node not in strict mode so I assumed it was referring to the global context. Running it in the browser, I see it refers to the instance of Foo.

Comment: @MatthewMoran When you call a function with `new` the value of `this` will *always* be an instance of the function. That's how the `new` operator works - it creates an instance then calls the function with `this` set to it. If you *don't* use `new`, then `this` will be undefined. Or the global object in sloppy mode. Unless you override it with `.call`, for example. Arrow functions are not constructable, they cannot be called with `new`.